# Laravel 9 - Missing required parameter for [Route: trial.show] [URI: evaluation/{evaluation}/trial/{trial}] [Missing parameter: trial]

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `evaluation` model that has many `trials`.  I can create a trial and query through my trials and output them to my `evaluation.show` view.  My problem is when I want to create a link to my `trial.edit` or `trial.show` routes, I keep getting error `Missing required parameter for [Route: trial.show] [URI: evaluation/{evaluation}/trial/{trial}] [Missing parameter: trial]`. I know I am missing something obvious, but I've exhausted my brain output.

**web.php**

```
...
Route::get('/evaluation/{evaluation}/trial/create', App\Http\Livewire\Trial\Create::class)->name('trial.create');
Route::get('/evaluation/{evaluation}/trial/{trial}/edit', App\Http\Livewire\Trial\Edit::class)->name('trial.edit');
Route::get('/evaluation/{evaluation}/trial/{trial}', App\Http\Livewire\Trial\Show::class)->name('trial.show');
...
```

**livewire/evaluation/show.blade.php**

```
    ...
@foreach($trials as $trial)
    <a href="{{route('trial.show', $trial->id)}}" class="block hover:bg-gray-50">
@endforeach
    ...
```

**Livewire/Evaluation/Show.php**

```
...
public function mount(Evaluation $evaluation, Trial $trial) {
    $this->evaluation = $evaluation;
    $this->trial = $trial;
}

public function render()
{
    $trials = Trial::where('evaluation_id', $this->evaluation->id)->get();

    return view('livewire.evaluation.show', compact('trials'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route(s) take two parameters (`{evaluation}` and `{trial}`), you only pass one in `{{route('trial.show', $trial->id)}}`.

Add the evaluation id (assuming `$evaluation->id` holds that id):

```
<a href="{{route('trial.show', [$evaluation->id, $trial->id])}}" class="block hover:bg-gray-50">
```

Comment: The part `[Missing parameter: trial]` of that message can be a bit misleading, since it was actually the `evaluation` parameter that was missing. Route parameters take order, so the first parameter you added has been recognized as the `evaluation` parameter.

Comment: You might be able to set a default parameter for `evaluation` using [Default Values](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#default-values) if you want, never used it though

Answer (score 1):

I found I was missing the ID from the model and that because the id was null, this caused this error.